# How do I join the most recent row in one table to most recent row in another table (oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data that looks like this:

**Nodes**

```
Name    Attribute    Date
14      A1           11-OCT-2015
14      A2           7-Nov-2015
12      B1           11-Nov-2015
```

**Vectors**

```
Node    V_NAME    color   Date
14      V1        blue   11-OCT-2015
14      V1        red    10-Nov-2015
14      V2        blue   7-Nov-2015
12      V3        black  11-Nov-2015
12      V4        black  11-Nov-2015
```

I want to get results like below

```
Node   Attribute    V_NAME   color 
14      A2           V1      red
14      A2           V2      blue
12      B1           V3      black
12      B1           V4      black
```

Date column in both tables are not same

Comment: You say recent, but A1 is the most recent and isnt match with V1. Also why A2 and B1 have doble match but A1 doesnt have any?

Comment: What is the data type for your `"Date"` field?

Comment: Date filed is timestamp

Comment: As I mentioned in the question .. dates in both tables are not same .. two different processed populates them, which are independent to each other.

Comment: Doesn't mean they won't join?

Comment: for short time .. yes they may not have join .. but while running this query it should have entries in both table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use two cte to calculate the most recent row in each category. Then join both.

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8b18c/28)**

```
WITH n_node as (
    SELECT "Name", "Attribute",
           row_number() over (partition by "Name" order by "Date" DESC) rn
    FROM Nodes 
), 
n_vector as (
    SELECT "Node", "V_NAME", "color",
           row_number() over (partition by "Node", "V_NAME" order by "Date" DESC) rn
    FROM Vectors 
)
SELECT "Name", "Attribute", "V_NAME", "color"
FROM n_node
JOIN n_vector 
  ON n_node.rn = n_vector.rn
 AND n_node.rn = 1
 AND n_node."Name" = n_vector."Node"
ORDER BY "Name" DESC
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| Name | Attribute | V_NAME | color |
|------|-----------|--------|-------|
|   14 |        A2 |     V1 |   red |
|   14 |        A2 |     V2 |  blue |
|   12 |        B1 |     V3 | black |
|   12 |        B1 |     V4 | black |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  v.Node,
  n.Attribute,
  v.V_NAME,
  v.color
from Nodes n inner join Vector v
  on n.Name = v.Node and n.Date = v.Date
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d3464/1

Comment: Based on the data I figure this would return 4 rows.  Are you suggesting any different?

Comment: n.Date and V.Date are not equal in the data set

Comment: What data types are they? (see also question from @PM77-1)

Comment: they are timestamp  (Date field)

Comment: @MatRichardson Your output doesnt match OP request

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to only return a vector of no other with same V_NAME has a later date.

```
select v.Node, n.Attribute, v.V_NAME, v.color
from nodes as n
  join vectors as v on n.name = v.node
where not exists (select 1 from vectors as v2
                  where v2.v_name = v.v_name
                    and v2.date > v.date)
```

Alternative answer, use a sub-query to pick each v_name's latest date:

```
select v.Node, n.Attribute, v.V_NAME, v.color
from nodes as n
  join vectors as v on n.name = v.node
where (v.v_name, v.date) = (select v_name, max(date) from vectors group by v_name)
```

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, thanks for the fiddle. Unfortunately sqlfiddle seems to have too much load to respond at the moment.